# identifying a type passed in a func

Tags: c#, func

I have an interface that looks like this

```
public interface IMyService
{
    T ServiceProxy<T>(Func<IService, T> request) where T : Response;
}
```

And it’s usage looks like this:

```
_mysvc.ServiceProxy((p) => p.Execute(new ActivateAccountRequest()));
_mysvc.ServiceProxy((p) => p.Execute(new DeleteAccountRequest()));
```

i.e. Various different requests types are sent to the ServiceProxy method wrapped in a Func. All requests subclass the same base class

I need to create a fake implementation of this interface for testing purposes. And I’d like to do different things based on what type of request is passed to the method

But I can’t work out how to identify the type of request passed in to the ServiceProxy method

e.g if it is a ActivateAccountRequest I want to do one thing, if it is a DeleteAccountRequest I want to do another

any ideas?

Comment: If you want to do different things based on the argument type, use overloads instead of generics.

Comment: `typeof(T)` works. *Why* do you want to do that though? The point of using generics is that you don't need to know the concrete type. If you do, you probably need to use overloads or some kind of Visitor implementation (which also uses overloads).

Comment: If you are testing surely you know exactly what the inputs to your test are and therefore what the type is for any given test... Can you explain a bit more what your tests are and what you are trying to do in them that depends on the type?

Comment: @Chris is right. You should be stubbing your tests appropriately. For instance, if you are using Moq, you can configure the method such that it returns what you want when the type is whatever you expect.

Comment: You cannot figure it out without passing Expression as stated in the answer below, because you cannot inspect what code is called inside delegate.

Comment: I am creating a fake implementation of this for a QA environment where the real implementation cannot be installed. So I just need an implementation that returns pre-canned responses. e.g. if a certain request is recieved, return a specific response

Answer (score 1):

Change your interface to:

```
 T ServiceProxy<T>(Expression<Func<IService, T>> request) where T : Response;
```

Now use this extension method to get function parameters:

```
 public static IEnumerable<object> GetFunctionParameters<TInput, TOutput>(this Expression<Func<TInput, TOutput>> expression)
        {
            var call = expression.Body as MethodCallExpression;
            if (call == null)
                throw new ArgumentException("Not a method call");

            foreach (Expression argument in call.Arguments)
            {
                LambdaExpression lambda = Expression.Lambda(argument, expression.Parameters);
                Delegate d = lambda.Compile();
                yield return d.DynamicInvoke(new object[1]);
            }
        }
```

And then simply call `request.GetFunctionParameters().First().GetType();`

Comment: sorry - changing the interface is not an option I have